# Slow MySQL query with subquery from table

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I am trying to bring back a string based on an IF statement but it is extremely slow.

It has something to do with the first subquery but I am unsure of how to rearrange this as to bring back the same results but faster.

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT IF
(
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT enquiryId, type 
                FROM parts_enquiries, parts_service_types AS pst 
                WHERE parts_enquiries.serviceTypeId = pst.id
            ) AS parts
        WHERE parts.enquiryId = enquiries.id
    ) > 1, 'Mixed',
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT type 
        FROM parts_enquiries, parts_service_types AS pst 
        WHERE parts_enquiries.serviceTypeId = pst.id AND enquiryId = enquiries.id
    )
) AS partTypes
FROM  enquiries,
entities
WHERE enquiries.entityId = entities.id
```

How can I make it faster?

---

I have modified my original query below, but I am getting the error that subquery returns more than one row:

```
SELECT
(SELECT
   CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT type) > 1 THEN 'Mixed' ELSE `type` END AS type
FROM parts_enquiries 
INNER JOIN parts_service_types AS pst ON parts_enquiries.serviceTypeId = pst.id
INNER JOIN enquiries ON parts_enquiries.enquiryId = enquiries.id
INNER JOIN entities ON enquiries.entityId = entities.id
GROUP BY enquiryId) AS partTypes
FROM  enquiries,
entities
WHERE enquiries.entityId = entities.id
```

---

[image: EXPLAIN result]

Comment: First step is to add `EXPLAIN` in front of your `SELECT` statement, then post that here, then post the output of `CREATE TABLE` statement for each table in the query. Then someone who is smart and willing to help can devote some time to aid you in pursuit of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look if this query yields the same results:

```
SELECT 
   enquiryId, 
   CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT type) > 1 THEN 'Mixed' ELSE `type` END AS type
FROM parts_enquiries 
INNER JOIN parts_service_types AS pst ON parts_enquiries.serviceTypeId = pst.id
INNER JOIN enquiries ON parts_enquiries.enquiryId = enquiries.id
INNER JOIN entities ON enquiries.entityId = entities.id
GROUP BY enquiryId
```

But N.B.'s comment is still valid. To see if and index is used and other information we need to see the `EXPLAIN` and the table definitions.

Comment: I get Error Code: 5 Out of memory (Needed 268435377 bytes) when I try this.

Comment: You should increase your database buffers if you get this error, this is a problem with resources on your box and not with tomboms query.

Comment: @tombom Got it to work on its own by decreasing my key_buffer from 8GB to 20 MB. How do I get this to work as a subquery? I'll accept as answer next.

Comment: Why do you want to have it as a subquery? I already joined to enquiries and entities. With the group by you should get one row per enquiryId, which is basically the same as the subquery you used before. There's no need to put my query in a subquery again. Does my query not yield the same result as your first query?

Comment: @tombom To a point, it appears that it is not grouping on enquiryId at all.

Comment: But you have no errors like "ambigious column enquiryId" or whatever?

Comment: @tombom No nothing like that :( I've ran it in SQL workbench and group is working but I don't understand why I am getting the subquery multiple rows error.

Comment: Your subquery thing doesn't make much sense when combined with my query. Best thing would be, you provided sample data or the explain plan and table definitions. Either we optimize it by rewriting query, and I don't understand what the problem should be with my query without sample data, or we optimize it by using indexes efficiently.

Comment: @tombom I have took a SS of the EXPLAIN results from the query, please see edit.

Comment: The `explain` actually looks okay, can you provide sample data and desired result? preverably on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @tombom I got it to work by putting your answer as a table in the FROM part of my main query, I then selected type from that and it got me what I wanted! Has halved the total query time so thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want.

I would first pre-query your parts enquiries and parts service types looking for both the count and MINIMUM of the part 'type', grouped by the enquiry ID.

then, run your IF() against that result.  If the distinct count is > 0, then 'Mixed'. If only one, since I did the MIN(), it would only have the description of that one value that you desire anyhow.

```
SELECT
      E.ID
      IF ( PreQuery.DistTypes > 1, 'Mixed', PreQuery.FirstType ) as PartType
   from 
      Enquiries E
         JOIN ( SELECT
                      PE.EnquiryID,
                      COUNT( DISTINCT PE.ServiceTypeID ) as DistTypes,
                      MIN( PST.Type ) as FirstType
                   from 
                      Parts_Enquiries PE
                         JOIN Parts_Service_Types PST
                            ON PE.ServiceTypeID = PST.ID
                   group by 
                      PE.EnquiryID ) as PreQuery
            ON E.ID = PreQuery.EnquiryID
```